# How to run KNN with cosine_similarity?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I'm trying to run `cosine_similarity` with `KNN Classifier` with no success.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10,  metric=cosine_similarity).fit(x, y)
```

shape of x (150 sample with 4 features):

```
(150, 4)
```

shape of y:

```
(150,)
```

I'm getting error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead
```

I have tried to reshape `x` with `reshape(-1,1)` or `rehsape(1,-1)` with no success.

How can I run  `KNN Classifier` on this dataset (x have 4 features) with `cosine_similarity` ?

Comment: Pls provide sample data for X and y. Try this KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10,  metric = 'cosine').fit(X, y)

Comment: You should also reshape `y`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the cosine similarity is only supported by the brute-force variant of the nearest neighbor algorithm. You have two options here to make this work:

**Option 1**: Explicitly specify to use the brute-force algorithm with `algorithm='brute'`:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier


X, y = make_classification(n_samples=150, n_features=4, random_state=42)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10, algorithm='brute',  metric=cosine_similarity)
knn.fit(X, y)
```

**Option 2**: Specify `metric='cosine'` which will automatically pick the brute-force algorithm:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier


X, y = make_classification(n_samples=150, n_features=4, random_state=42)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10,  metric='cosine')
knn.fit(X, y)
```

If you want to read more about the different nearest neighbor algorithms you can refer to the [user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#nearest-neighbor-algorithms).